# how to write a simple python websockets client

Tags: python, websocket

How to write a simple Python3 websockets client ?

Given https://github.com/Pithikos/python-websocket-server (a multi-client server implementation) which has been tested with the authors provided web client (ie. javascript), I like to write a simple python3 client using standard python websockets module. I expect the client to send a text message and get an answer back (sort of like an echo server). Nothing fancy on the client, no concurrency, just connect, send, recv and close (or exit).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import websockets

req = 'joe'
if sys.argv[1:]:
    req = sys.argv[1]

with websockets.connect("ws://localhost:9001") as ws:
    print("req: %s" % (req) )
    ws.send(req)
    res = ws.recv()
    print("res: %s" % (res) )
```

And when I run it ...

```
medi@medi:~/proto/python/d4> ./client 'hello Joe'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./client", line 10, in <module>
    with websockets.connect("ws://localhost:9001") as ws:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

I was expecting to be able to send() and recv().  I am having difficulty finding python based code (have seen lots of JS clients) sample.

Comment: Do we sockets support `with`? The error is suggesting that they don't.

Comment: did you check [websockets documentation](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) ?

Comment: Yes in fact the "with" constructe was borrowed from sample code at websockets documentation. The doc actually uses "async with ...." but I don't need any concurrency, just single step execution is ok

Answer (score 0):

This is an async websocket client that supports asyncio. You need to use it like this:

```py
import asyncio
import websockets


async def main():
    async with websockets.connect(...) as websocket:
        ...


asyncio.run(main())
```